# Compiling pdflatex when evince or atril are open in the back ground causes errors in VIm

Tags: vim, latex

I have the common workflow:

```
$ pdflatex doc.tex
$ atril doc.tex &
$ vim doc.tex
```

And if I compile doc again from within vim using the vim-latex suite, I get many errors within my vim screen. Errors along the line:

```
(atril:10737): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_widget_get_parent: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed

(atril:10737): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid unclassed pointer in cast to 'EvWebView'

(atril:10737): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

(atril:10737): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_handlers_disconnect_matched: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed

(atril:10737): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

(atril:10737): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_handlers_disconnect_matched: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed

(atril:10737): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

(atril:10737): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_handlers_disconnect_matched: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed

(atril:10737): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_ref_sink: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

(atril:10737): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
```

The same error happens with the pdf viewer `evince`. Is there a reason for this? I have searched for a patch for the warnings, but to no avail.